# How to break a numpy.in1d function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if even just 1 element in array1 is in array2, and if it is  break.

I found numpy.in1d as a good function, but I can't figure out how to break if an element is found.

Sample code:

```
import numpy

array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

array3 = ['a', 'g', 'h']
array4 = ['i', 'd', 'j']

twoDArray1 = [array1, array2]
twoDArray2 = [array3, array4]

for array in twoDArray1:
    for secondArray in twoDArray2:
        # how to break on the first check since it already matched?
        print(array , " in " ,  secondArray , numpy.in1d(array, secondArray))
```

Here is an [online sample](https://www.online-python.com/Wq9UFDeyKY) to try

Comment: Look at the code (it's python).  If one of the arrays is small enough, it iterates through it's elements, and `|` (or) the results.  So you could implement that loop yourself with a break.  But if the arrays are about the same size it uses `unique`  and `argsort`.  That can't be short-circuited.  As a general rule, the fast `numpy` methods can't be short-circuited - they are designed to work with the whole array, and avoid python-level loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resort to [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression, it has a short-circuiting behaviour unlike `np.in1d`:

```
any(val in secondArray for val in array)
```

`np.in1d` needs to return an array of length `len(array)` so it checks every `val` in array. That would be the worst case scenario of `any` in case only last `val` is contained in the other or no intersection.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks!